# How to grep lines with adjacent repeated digits

Tags: shell-script

I have a scenario where data is in a file like this.

Data :

```
1234 2271 4423
8901 1234 2569
1234 5678 9107
1134 7896 6780
```

The output should be :

```
    1234 2271 4423
    8901 1234 2569
    1134 7896 6780
```

I need to search each entire line and if I find any adjacent digits are repeated, then display the entire line. "Adjacent" digits can be separated by spaces (but not by other digits).

For example :

```
1234 2271 4423  -> in this 2271 -> [2][2] 71 -> the 2 digit is adjacently repeated.
```

Similarly there is another one which is adjacently repeated -> 4423 -> [4][4]23

```
1134 7896 6780
In this also -> [1][1]34 and 789[6] [6]780
```

I got this solution: can someone explain what it exactly means and any other simple approach? Please share with proper explanation, so I will get some idea:

```
command 1 : grep '\([0-9]\) *\1'
command 2 : grep '\([0-9]\)\s*\1'
command 3 : grep  '\(\d\)\s*\1'
command 4 : grep -e '([0-9])\1' -e '([0-9]) \1'
```

Comment: Apparently most answers overlooked "can someone explain what it exactly means". The answer: [Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html). "Any other simple approach?" You will hardly find something as simple as that.

Comment: @Quasímodo you are right, although actually that means the answer should be closed as "needing more focus" ...

Comment: @AdminBee If because of the 4 commands instead of only 1, I agree. But if the question contained just 1 of them, it would be OK (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` program should work:

```
awk '{buf=gensub(/ */,"","g",$0); split(buf,chars,""); last=chars[1];
      for (i=2;i<=length(buf);i++) {if (chars[i]==last) {print; next}; last=chars[i]}}' test.txt
```

This will first remove all spaces from the input line and store the result in a string `buf`. It will then split `buf` into an array of single characters, `chars`. That will be parsed to see if to consecutive characters are found. If so, the line is printed.

(This is a solution that doesn't rely on RegEx backreferences)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility with GNU `grep`, if I understand correctly:

```
grep -P "([0-9])[[:blank:]]?\1" file
```

Output:

```
1234 2271 4423
8901 1234 2569
1134 7896 6780
```

Answer (score 0):

While not being as interesting as using backreferences and the question mark quantifier, you could do this using pipes and a simple regex, with the advantage of it being easier to understand IMHO.

`tr -d ' ' | egrep '00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99' | sed -r 's/..../& /g'`

Or you could do all of it in sed but it is less readable:

`sed -r 's/ //g;/00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99/!d;s/..../& /g'`

The basic concept of both of them is to remove the space between the numbers, use a simple regex to match lines with adjacent numbers, then put the space back in to print it out.